# Upgrade PHP to latest version on CentOS 4.5

Tags: php, centos

I'm a Linux newbie but I need to upgrade PHP on CentOS 4.5 to the latest version -- or at least 5.2.2 or better. What's the easiest way to do that? The latest available via yum seems to be 5.1.6 and I can't find anything on the Web that seems to work.

Comment: I have the same question, but for a centos 5 production box.  We used to use utterramblings's packages, but the maintainer's been MIA for over a year, so I'm hesitant to use another 3rd party repository, and I'm naturally hesitant to use the testing repo on a production box.  In an ideal world, I'd like to see redhat's "AppStack" packages ported to centos: http://www.redhat.com/appstack/

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Remi Collet Repository](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/). Repo configs for RHEL/CentOS 4 are available ([i386](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/el4.i386/repoview/remi-release.html) and [x86_64](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/el4.x86_64/repoview/remi-release.html) )

Answer (score 1):

There is a repository on yum called c5 testing i think. It has PHP 5.2.6 A note though, not all modules in PHP are in this testing repo, and some you have to update yourself.

So this is not something I would recommend on a live server. I did this on a dev server and had some problems.

```
yum --enablerepo=c5-testing install php
```

I think this works, i have the commands at work but you can google some info regarding the c5 testing repo and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If al else fails, you can always compile from source. I've done it before on CentOS and it actually works quite smoothly.